# How I can I loop over prefetched cells?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I'd like to loop over loaded cells of an UICollectionView and highlight (by calling a cell method) a particular cell based on its model.

I can easily loop over visible cells, with `collectionView.visibleCells`, but I don't know how to reach prefetched cells.

Of course, disabling cell prefetching solves the problem, but I lose all its benefits.

Using a prefetchDataSource won't solve the problem, because the boolean that controls the cell's highlight state is not correctly set at the time of prefetching.

I might use the prefetchDataSource to keep track of loaded cells, but from what I read in the documentation, you don't have the actual cells at that point.

Should I just disable cell prefetching or is there a better way?
Something easy like `collectionView.visibleCells` would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that there are some "prefetched cells" that aren't in `collectionView.visibleCells`?

Comment: @algrid yes, I'm quite sure. Disabling cell prefetching makes everything works as expected.

Comment: What exactly is the problem when cell prefetching is enabled?

Comment: A cell is loaded. Since it was prefetched, it's still not visible, so it won't be referenced inside `collectionView.visibleCells`. I need to call that cell view's `setHighlight` method (it's a custom method, nothing to do with the default highlighting). I can't manage to do that, because prefetched cells are not listed anywhere.
A delegate method similar to `collectionView(_:cellForItemAt:)
` that would be called before a cell becomes visible would solve my problem. I would be able to set proper highlighting before the cell actually appears.

Comment: what happens if you call your `setHighlight` method in `collectionView(_:cellForItemAt:)`?

Comment: I already do. In fact, it works perfectly fine, if the cell wasn't prefetched.

Comment: That's weird. In my sample I 1) change all visibleCells state 2) change datasource and that's enough to change everything.